# FTP mirror with version control

Tags: linux, windows, ftp, svn, version-control

Consider this:

- I have ftp server ABC
- ~30GB and thousands of directories and files
- I have read only user to this ftp
- this is not my server, I do not have access to it's administration/configuration

Can I create FTP mirror with version control?

I wanted to automatically sync this ABC server with my local copy and next I wanted to make a commit with some version control system. Are there any existing tools for such thing (doesn't matter linux or windows)?

First thought - to use WinSCP automatic synchronization commands and when it finish make commit with SVN - is this good solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a batch file that does the following:

1) `winscp synchronize` to get the files
2) `svn add` to version control any new files
3) `svn commit` at the end to commit the files

*Keep in mind that Version Control works best with text based files.*

---

#### Example

This example works for me:

```
winscp /script=config.txt /log=log.log /xmllog=log.xml
svn add C:\localFTP\root --force
svn commit C:\localFTP\root\ -m "commit after ftp synchronize"
```

Where config.txt is this:

```
open ftp://Anonymous:pass@ftp.example.com
synchronize local C:\localFTP\root /remote/path
exit
```

---

#### Notes

1) Run the bat from `C:\localFTP`

2) If `winscp` is not in the `%PATH%` add it or put this at the top of the bat file:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\
```

3) `svn` should be in the `%PATH%` if it isn't you will need to add it